# How to restore the html content after page reload?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have the HTML content like the below:

```
<ul class="wpProQuiz_questionList" data-type="single" data-question_id="114">
    <li class="wpProQuiz_questionListItem" data-remember&gt;="" data-pos="0">
        <span style="display:none;">1. </span>
        <label>
            <input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" value="1" name="question_49_114">
            option 1
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="wpProQuiz_questionListItem" data-remember&gt;="" data-pos="1">
        <label>
            <input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" value="2" name="question_49_114">
            option 2
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="wpProQuiz_questionListItem" data-remember&gt;="" data-pos="2">
        <label>
            <input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" value="3" name="question_49_114">
            option 3
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="wpProQuiz_questionListItem" data-remember&gt;="" data-pos="3">
```

I also have a next button which on clicking goes to the next `li` element and hides the previous one. Inside the `li` tag we have many options to select.
I want to store all selected options and restore it after page reload and continue from where it was left.

Comment: It could be done in a lot of ways, but keep it simple, search for 'localStorage' or $_SESSION. If your user is logged, you could use the database too (I think this isn't the best option). You should show some research/work done in the question, SO is not for code being done, read more in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also, take care, you have not valid html in the `data-remember&gt;=""`

Answer (score 1):

Youll want to store it in localStorage and then retrieve.

```
   $('.next').click(function(){
       // whatever your code is to retrieve the next li
       // store it as var pos
       // then do this.
       localStorage.setItem("chosenList", pos);           

   });
   // I used .next here as an example, I have no idea what your click handler is actually called.  
   //So just put it whereever you are handling that
```

Then at the top of your jquery, something like.

```
     if(localStorage.getItem("chosenList")){
        // apply active class to the chosen element.
        // I dont have all your code so don't know how you're doing this.
        // but something like this
         var pos = localStorage.getItem("chosenList");
         $('*[data-pos="'+pos+'"]').addClass('active');
        // Im using .active as an example.  I dont know what css you are using, if any, to open the menu.
       // Point is, you now have a stored value, you can retrieve and apply it wherever.
     }
```

Again...I don't know your exact code for the click handler, and for applying active to the list elements, so it wont beexactly like this.  But this is the idea.